# udp client sending ICMP "port unreachable" when receiveing messages from the server

Tags: sockets, networking, udp, icmp, luasocket

**Moved: https://superuser.com/questions/782549/udp-client-sending-icmp-port-unreachable-when-receiveing-messages-from-the-ser**

I have a udp client using luasocket, basically doing this (with a few layers of abstraction, but this is what's going on there):

```
s=socket.udp()
s:setsockname("*",0)
s:setpeername(socket.dns.toip("example.com"),64299)
s:settimeout(0)
s:send(...)
s:settimeout(10)
msg,err=s:receive()
s:settimeout(0)
print(msg,err)
```

while seeing everything's fine in the server's debug output (ssh to the remote host), i get a "timeout" error in the client.

when inspecting everything with client-side wireshark, I see the packet my client sent, and a response packet from the server (correct port and everything), AND an ICMP "port unreachable" packet sent from my client host to the server in response to it's (correct) response.

what's going on there? I tried everything, including resetting my iptables to "accept everything", but my client still sends the "port unreachable".

the relevant packets are:

```
From            To                  Len Description
192.168.2.100   95.143.172.171  UDP 61  Source port: 45025  Destination port: 64299
  000e8f11e7000025229835a908004500002f4008400040112b6fc0a802645f8facabafe1fb2b001b28d794d2000ec8360100aa81a477616e74a3756964
95.143.172.171  192.168.2.100   UDP 60  Source port: 64299  Destination port: 45025
  0025229835a9000e8f11e70008004500002b000040003911727b5f8facabc0a80264fb2bafe100172e8d94d2000e0ea10100a681a3756964ff000000
192.168.2.100   95.143.172.171  ICMP 85 Destination unreachable (Port unreachable)
  000e8f11e7000025229835a9080045c00047061d00004001a492c0a802645f8facab0303cc6c000000004500002b000040003911727b5f8facabc0a80264fb2bafe100172e8d94d2000e0ea10100a681a3756964ff
```

Firewall, in case it's important (which I don't think, because iptables doesn't increment any INPUT packet counters while this happens):

```
$ sudo iptables -S
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --sport 64299 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10001:30000 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Some servers block `ICMP` (for security reasons) which might explain it.

Comment: @alfasin Explain it how?

Comment: @EJP not sure if I understand you question, you can set `iptables -P DROP` to drop ICMP requests

Comment: @alfasin the problem is there's no reason why that port should be unreachable, because i just sent the request packet from it.

Comment: @alfasin Come off it. My question is clear. How would that explain why he *gets* an ICMP UNREACH?

Comment: my problem is: the client sends the "request", the server sends the "response", but the client doesn't see it (timeout) while the client's OS sends an "icmp unreachable" back to the server, because the server's response reached the client's OS, which somehow has forgotten that the client exists

Comment: @EJP take it easy man :-)  I didn't get the part that the response actually gets to the client...

Comment: @alfasin that's the part that I really don't understand either, I see the response in wireshark, but my OS seems to be unable to correctly send it back to the client o__O

Comment: @alfasin You didn't get the part where there is no ICMP request here to block, only an ICMP response that doesn't get blocked.

Comment: @usr That's pretty vague. We've already got a lot further than that. It is about a problem that causes the client machine to drop the datagram and issue an ICMP unreachable. If it was a network problem, there wouldn't be anything in the sniff trace at all. If you have another explanation, post it as an answer.

Comment: @EJP you're right, this is vague. My point is that this question is off topic. It is valid otherwise. I don't mean to answer and I already upvoted yours.

Comment: @usr that's what I don't understand. while I agree with EJP and you that this turned out to be off-topic here, it's definitely not my firewall (I even unloaded the iptables modules for testing), so I'm afraid EJP's answer is technically incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Your client-side firewall is actively blocking inbound UDP.

Comment: well, no, i'm afraid it's not. at least if I understand it correctly. because: `iptables -t filter -A INPUT -i eth0 -p UDP --sport 64299 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: i see that it is the only possible explanation, but I don't see how that could be, because I explicitly accept the source port. also I accept all established/related states, which should implicitly cover this case too (iptables remembers IP/Port pairs for stateless "connections" like UDP).

Comment: even stranger: inspecting `iptables -vL ; ./client.lua ; iptables -vL` i get 0 packets for these rules before AND after the client ran; while the `reject-with icmp-port-unreachable` counter didn't change either

Comment: The question is now about iptables and is therefore off topic. Try superuser.

Comment: are you kidding me? the question is not about iptables, because if iptables would be blocking my packet, i would see the counters being incremented, which I don't, as I said there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24720022/udp-client-sending-icmp-port-unreachable-when-receiveing-messages-from-the-ser#comment38342623_24720283

Comment: It isn't about your code. Your code is executing perfectly. The read timeout and ICMP message both indicate that an external factor is in play. Ergo off topic.

Comment: assuming there's no strange bug in luasocket closing my udp socket between sending and trying to receive, I guess you're right then, closing this question and moving it to SU.